# Formato Currency en un input de Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Cuando queremos formatear como moneda una etiqueta en Angular2 usamos el Pipe Currency:

```
<p>{{cantidad | currency}}</p>
```

Eso funciona a la perfección, pero si lo que queremos es que el usuario meta una cantidad de dinero en un input, ¿cómo hacemos para que se formatee correctamente?

Lo que querría es algo como esto (este ejemplo NO funciona, por supuesto):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="cantidad | currency"></ion-input>
```

Y el comportamiento esperado sería que aunque el usuario teclee "10,2", cuando el input pierda el foco en el input se vea "10,20 €" y en el model tengamos "10.2".

Nota: sé que podría separar por un lado [ngModel]="cantidad" y por otro lado manejar el evento (change) o el (ngModelChange), pero buscaba una solución más elegante y cómoda.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No uses `[(ngModel)]`. En su lugar usa el evento `(change)` y el atributo `[value]` para controlar manualmente el valor.

```
<input [value]="cantidad" (change)="updateValue($event.target.value)">
```

En tu componente debes tener entonces algo como esto

```
import {formatCurrency, getCurrencySymbol} from '@angular/common';

....

updateValue(value: string) {
    let val = parseInt(value, 10);
    if (Number.isNaN(val)) {
      val = 0;
    }
    this.cantidad = formatCurrency(val, 'en-US', getCurrencySymbol('USD', 'wide'));
}
```

Básicamente estás bindeando el valor del input a una variable de tu componente que actualizas manualmente cada vez que hay un cambio en el control. El valor lo actualizas justo después que el usuario termina de escribir.

Es recomendable que uses las funciones que vienen incluidas en el Angular para manejo de monedas usando internacionalización ya que en todas las culturas la posición de la moneda no va en el mismo lugar.

Answer (score 3):

Mejor haz una validación que compruebe que es del tipo currency o qué contiene dos decimales antes de guardarlo para evitar problemas al convertirlo. De otra manera tendrás que cambiar el formato en la lógica del componente y agregar los decimales si te pasan un número entero.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, te recomiendo los [formularios reactivos de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), ya que te permiten llevar la lógica y gestionar los cambios de estado en el lado del componente, en lugar de dentro del HTML.

Si quieres seguir utilizando ngModel, lo mejor es hacer una `CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR` en forma de Directiva que se llame currencyMask, y dentro de la directiva te subscribes a los eventos `onBlur` y `onFocus` mediante `@HostListener`. Por ejemplo:

```
  typescript
  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onfocus(value, target) {
    // [...]
  }
```

Es mas tedioso, aunque te permite tener como valor un Number en el componente y modificar la "fachada" del valor. Así, cuando hagas focus quitas todo tipo de formateo, y cuando hagas blur, formateas para que se vea como tu desees, sin cambiar tu modelo a un valor que no sea válido.

Esto básicamente es lo que hace https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

modifica el ngModel en la etiqueta para poder usar el pipe

```
<input [ngModel]="cantidad | currency">
```